# How to extract subsets in a list based on the largest element in the subset?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

For example, if i have a list as following:

```
 example = {
  {{a, b, 3}, {c, d, 2}, {e, f, 1}},
  {{a, b, 5}, {c, d, 2}, {e, f, 8}},
  {{a, b, 4}, {c, d, 3}, {e, f, 2}},
  {{a, b, 1}, {c, d, 2}, {e, f, 4}}
  }
```

How to create a new list which join the subset which has the largest 3rd element?
for example, in the first line:  {{a, b, 3}, {c, d, 2}, {e, f, 1}}
“3” is the largest number at the third position of each subset, so i only extract `{a, b, 3}`
Eventually, i will get a new list as following:

```
 newset = {
  {a, b, 3},
  {e, f, 8},
  {a, b, 4},
  {e, f, 4}
  }
```

so how to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
First@MaximalBy[#, Last] & /@ example
```

> ```
> {{a, b, 3}, {e, f, 8}, {a, b, 4}, {e, f, 4}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

```
Map[Last @* SortBy[Last]] @ example
```

> ```
>  {{a, b, 3}, {e, f, 8}, {a, b, 4}, {e, f, 4}}
> ```

Also

```
#[[First @ Ordering[Last /@ #, -1]]] & /@ example
```

> ```
> {{a, b, 3}, {e, f, 8}, {a, b, 4}, {e, f, 4}}
> ```